# Best action hook to create custom post and assign taxonomy terms to it on plugin activation?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-taxonomy, init

When I install the plugin, I want to create 10 CPTs of a particular type, which I define in the `init` action hook, and want to assign 10 terms of a custom taxonomy, which too is defined in an `init` callback. I tried doing it on `register_activation_hook`, but the CPT's terms are not set. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, I needed to set the terms using post ID. So after every insert, I used the ID to set the terms https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms

Someone might find this useful.